# How to create a BarChart or a LineChart in Javafx Using ObservableLists

Tags: java, javafx, bar-chart, linechart

I'm trying to generate statistical graphs (BarCharts and LineCharts) from the data saved in an sql database using Java. 
The Data is expected to change from time to time.

I have tried using ObservableLists but am getting error messages.

Below is what I have tried so far;
NOTE: This resides in the DatabaseHandler class

```
public ObservableList<BarChart.Data> getItemGraphStatistics(){
        ObservableList<BarChart.Data> data = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

        String sql = "SELECT itemID, COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT itemID FROM SALES UNION ALL SELECT itemID FROM STOCK) t GROUP BY itemID";
        System.out.println(sql );
        ResultSet rs = handler.execQuery(sql);
        try{

            while(rs.next()){
                String item= rs.getString("itemID");
                int count = rs.getInt(2);

                data.add(new BarChart.Data(item+ "(" + count + ")", count));

            }
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(DatabaseHandler.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        return data;

    }
```

On running the above am getting

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: javafx.scene.chart.XYChart$Data cannot be cast to javafx.scene.chart.XYChart$Series
```

When i try to change BarChart.Data to BarChart.Series, I get unable to convert int to observableList error message.

Below is an example of the trial of the above;

```
import com.jfoenix.controls.JFXButton;
import com.jfoenix.controls.JFXRadioButton;
import com.jfoenix.controls.JFXTextField;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Dictionary;
import java.util.Hashtable;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.Event;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.chart.BarChart;
import javafx.scene.chart.CategoryAxis;
import javafx.scene.chart.LineChart;
import javafx.scene.chart.NumberAxis;
import javafx.scene.chart.PieChart;
import javafx.scene.control.ChoiceBox;
import javafx.scene.control.DatePicker;
import javafx.scene.control.ToggleGroup;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import sales.manager.database.DatabaseHandler;

/**
 * FXML Controller class
 *
 * @author Garande
 */
public class PerformanceAnalyzerController implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    private AnchorPane analysisHandler;
    @FXML
    private AnchorPane graphHandler;
    @FXML
    private PieChart piechart;
    @FXML
    private BarChart<?, ?> barchart;
    @FXML
    private LineChart<?, ?> linechart;

    @FXML
    private NumberAxis yBarGraph;
    @FXML
    private CategoryAxis xBarGraph;
    @FXML
    private NumberAxis yLineGraph;
    @FXML
    private CategoryAxis xLineGraph;

    DatabaseHandler handler = DatabaseHandler.getInstance();

    /**
     * Initializes the controller class.
     */
    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {


    }    

    @FXML
    private void performAnalysisOperation(ActionEvent event) {
        //Performing analysis operation

        barchart.setData(handler.getItemGraphStatistics());
        graphHandler.getChildren().add(barchart);
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't believe the code you've shown should be throwing that error. Please provide a [mcve] demonstrating the issue. Note an `XYChart` holds an `ObservableList<Series>`and each `Series` holds an `ObservableList<Data>`. Also, you [shouldn't use raw types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it).

Comment: @Slaw I have made changes to the question as requested. I have added an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `data` property of an  `XYChart` holds an `ObservableList<XYChart.Series>`. Each `XYChart.Series` *also* has a `data` property, but it holds an `ObservableList<XYChart.Data>`. The problem is your method returns an `ObservableList<XYChart.Data>` that you then try to set on `XYChart.data`—the types don't match. I'm not sure how you're getting a `ClassCastException`, as your code shouldn't even compile.

You need to wrap your list of data in a series, then add the series to the chart. You should also [avoid using raw types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it). Both `Series` and `Data` have type parameters but you don't specify them. Based on the way you're building your `Data`, your code should look something like (some code omitted for brevity):

```
public class PerformanceAnalyzerController {

    @FXML private BarChart<String, Number> barChart;

    @FXML
    private void performAnalysisOperation(ActionEvent event) {
        //Performing analysis operation

        ObservableList<XYChart.Data<String, Number>> data = handler.getItemsGraphicsStatisitics();
        XYChart.Series<String, Number> series = new XYChart.Series<>("Series Name", data);

        barchart.getData().setAll(series);
        graphHandler.getChildren().add(barchart);
    }

}
```

And:

```
// Use generic types
public ObservableList<XYChart.Data<String, Number>> getItemGraphStatistics(){
    ObservableList<XYChart.Data<String, Number>> data = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

    String sql = "SELECT itemID, COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT itemID FROM SALES UNION ALL SELECT itemID FROM STOCK) t GROUP BY itemID";
    System.out.println(sql );
    ResultSet rs = handler.execQuery(sql);
    try{

        while(rs.next()){
            String item= rs.getString("itemID");
            int count = rs.getInt(2);

            // add diamond operator "<>"
            data.add(new XYChart.Data<>(item+ "(" + count + ")", count));

        }
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(DatabaseHandler.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    return data;

}
```

*Note: I replaced uses of `BarChart.Data` with `XYChart.Data`, but I don't believe it matters in this case.*